# How to keep x-axis order (without it being sorted) while plotting a different factor at the same time

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given a matrix mat with a column "rplau", how to ensure ggplot keeps the same order as the x-labels are considered as in that vector of characters? For instance, when plotting, I'd like 928:1852 to follow after 1:927. How to do that? Sometimes it gets rearranged but sometimes it doesn't.

```
belplauPlot<-function(belplau_mat, xlab, color, y="rplau", x="index", is_log_scale=TRUE) {
  ggplot(as.data.frame(belplau_mat) %>% mutate(!!sym(y):=(if(is_log_scale) log(!!sym(y)) else !!sym(y))) %>% mutate(!!x:=xlab)) +
    geom_point(aes(x=!!sym(x),y=!!sym(y),colour=factor(color))) + 
    labs(color="") + theme_bw() + ylab(if (is_log_scale) paste0("log(",y,")") else y)
}
```

Right now, it's sorting according to `1 <= 1 <= 9` but I don't want that.

[image]

```
> belplauPlot(bel_plau3, part3_idx_s, lof_true3)
> part3_idx_s
[1] "1:927"     "928:1854"  "1855:2780"
> lof_true3
[1] 1 2 0
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to make `xlab` a factor, e.g.

Original code:

```r
library(tidyverse)

belplauPlot<-function(belplau_mat, xlab, color, y="rplau", x="index", is_log_scale=TRUE) {
  ggplot(as.data.frame(belplau_mat) %>% mutate(!!sym(y):=(if(is_log_scale) log(!!sym(y)) else !!sym(y))) %>% mutate(!!x:=xlab)) +
    geom_point(aes(x=!!sym(x),y=!!sym(y),colour=factor(color))) + 
    labs(color="") + theme_bw() + 
    ylab(if (is_log_scale) paste0("log(",y,")") else y)
}

bel_plau3 <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
rplau <- c(1:3)
part3_idx_s <- c("1:927", "928:1854", "1855:2780")
belplauPlot(belplau_mat = bel_plau3, xlab = part3_idx_s, color = c("deepskyblue", "firebrick3", "forestgreen"))
```

[image]

With `xlab` as a factor:

```r
belplauPlot<-function(belplau_mat, xlab, color, y="rplau", x="index", is_log_scale=TRUE) {
  ggplot(as.data.frame(belplau_mat) %>% mutate(!!sym(y):=(if(is_log_scale) log(!!sym(y)) else !!sym(y))) %>% mutate(!!x:=factor(xlab, levels = xlab))) +
    geom_point(aes(x=!!sym(x),y=!!sym(y),colour=factor(color))) + 
    labs(color="") + theme_bw() + 
    ylab(if (is_log_scale) paste0("log(",y,")") else y) +
    scale_color_identity()
}

bel_plau3 <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
rplau <- c(1:3)
part3_idx_s <- c("1:927", "928:1854", "1855:2780")
belplauPlot(belplau_mat = bel_plau3, xlab = part3_idx_s, color = c("deepskyblue", "firebrick3", "forestgreen"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

PS not sure how you want to handle "colors"; perhaps `scale_color_identity()`?

Comment: It worked! Thanks!